# How to sum over same indices of list of lists?

Tags: haskell

How can I sum a list of lists where all the values at the a index?

For example:

```
let k = [ [1,1,1], [2,2,2], [3,3,3] ]
sumFoo k
> [ 6, 6, 6]
```

---

I know that I can sum two lists as:

```
zipWith (+) [1,2,3] [2,3,4]
```

But what about a list of list? I tried something like:

```
foldr (\xs ys -> zipWith (+) xs ys) [] k
```

but that gives me an empty list!

Comment: You can easily fix your `foldr` version. The problem is that `zipWith _ [] = []`, e.g. the empty list zipped with anything is empty. Replace `[]` with `(repeat 0)` and you're set: `foldr (zipWith (+)) (repeat 0) k`. (Also note that `zipWith (+)` is equivalent to `\ a b -> zipWith (+) a b`.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have a matrix represented as a list of lists and want to extract the column sums. To do this, simply transpose the matrix and compute the row sums:

```
Prelude> import Data.List
Prelude Data.List> map sum . transpose $ [ [1,1,1], [2,2,2], [3,3,3] ]
[6,6,6]
```

Comment: This is only coincidentally correct. For `[[a, b, c], [d, e, f], [g, h, i]]` the OP wants not `[a+b+c, d+e+f, g+h+i]` but `[a+d+g, b+e+h, c+f+i]`.

Comment: @drozzy: In that case you need to `transpose` the list first (extract the columns from your list of rows, so to say).

Comment: @NiklasB. Yeah, I get that now. Funny misunderstanding though.

Answer (score 7):

To answer the OPs question:

```
foldl1 (zipWith (+)) k
```

should do the trick.  Foldl1 starts with the first element of the list as the accumulator value, which is what you want.

You can also use zipWith3, zipWith4, .... all the way up to 7, if you prefer.

-----------To find the overall sum ------

You first want to map sum over each element of the list (i.e. each nested list), and then run sum over the result.

So:

```
sum . map sum $ k
```

And that's it!

Notes if you're unfamiliar with . or $ syntax - $ is function application, but is right associative (saving you parentheses), and . is function composition.

Comment: That will however give `27` rather than `[6, 9, 12]`. Also, the brackets around the second `sum` are not needed.

Comment: thought op was looking for overall sum, rather than the individual elements.  good point.

Comment: Both of our initial answers were actually wrong.  OP is not trying to sum each sub-list, but find the result of a zip operation over multiple lists.

Comment: Yeah - sorry! Funnily, I picked the only example that would sum the same both ways!!!

Answer (score 3):

I think what you actually want here is something like:

```
import Data.List

positionalSums :: Num a => [[a]] -> [a]
positionalSums = map sum . transpose
```

When loaded into ghci:

```
> positionalSums [ [1,2,3], [2,3,4], [3,4,5] ]
[6,9,12]
> positionalSums [ [1,2,3], [2,3,104], [3,4,5] ]
[6,9,112]
```

`transpose` is the interesting function here.  It is what makes the whole thing work.  It basically swaps rows and columns, if you view a list of lists as a two-dimensional layout.

The key realization here was that you wanted to take the sum of the first element of each input list, the second element, the third...  The simplest way to do that is re-arrange the input list of lists such that each set of elements that you want to add together is together.  And that's exactly what transpose does.

Comment: Sorry see my update, I completely confused people with a bad example!

Comment: @drozzy You mean, you meant to ask the question I answered?  Why are you apologizing to me?