# Sum of list of lists inside a container?

Tags: haskell

Similar to [my previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9538584/sum-a-list-of-lists), but now I have a twist!

My data type looks like:

```
data Container = Container [Double]
```

and I want to sum over a list of these babies, like so:

```
sum' [Container [1,1,1], Container [2,2,2], Container [3,3,3]]
> [6,6,6]
```

Can't figure out a clean way of doing this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Define an accessor for your Container type:

```
content (Container x) = x
```

Then you can do this:

```
sum' = map sum . transpose . map content
```

Comment: Cool, I just constructed my data type with a record syntax and that took care of that!

Answer (score 2):

It's similar to the answer you received to your other question, except you need to take your inner lists out of their `Container`s:

```
import Data.List
sum' = map sum . transpose . map ( \ (Container cs) -> cs)
```

Answer (score 1):

The simplest thing to do would be to map the list before summing:

```
sum' = map (sum . (\ (Container ls) -> ls))
```

If you want to get a different sort of sum, you can just replace the `sum` function with something else.

Answer (score 0):

Well, I thought I'd add this to the answers you already have: one conventional way of doing this is to prefer record type definitions over the simpler product type definition you used, because record types give you an accessor functions for free.  So you'd define `Container` like this:

```
data Container = Container { getContents :: Double }
```

This defines `Container` as a record type with one field called `getContents`.  That's a funny name for a field compared to other types, but the thing is that now `getContents` has been defined as a function that extracts this field from a `Container`:

```
getContents (Container [1, 2, 3]) -- result: [1.0, 2.0, 3.0]
```

Given that, you have the same answer as Grzegorz gives, but with the implicitly defined `getContents` function in place of his explicitly defined `content` function:

```
sum' = map sum . transpose . map getContents
```